# Arrow key not working in component

Tags: delphi, pascal, custom-component

I use the Gecko SDK, a component that allows you to view web pages.
I use this component to create an html editor.

This problem happens when going off editing web pages.
The problem is that the arrow keys and the tab does not work with my component. I tried to find an answer to this problem, but I didn't find one. I found a track [here](http://www.phidels.com/php/index.php3?page=../php/trucs.htm&id=189), but the function does not work.

Function `Movement (dx, dy)` does not exist. Thank you for helping me solve this problem.

```
Procedure Tform1.TraiteMessages(Var msg : TMsg; Var Handled: boolean);
var
  dx, dy : integer;
begin   dx: 0; dy := 0; 
  With msg do
  begin
    IF Message = WM_KEYDOWN then
    Case  wparam of
      VK_LEFT  : dx := -1;
      VK_RIGHT : dx :=  1;
      VK_UP    : dy := -1;
      VK_DOWN  : dy :=  1;
    end;
  end;
  IF (dy = 0) AND (Dx = 0) then Handled := false else
  begin
    handled := true;     // message traité
    Mouvement(dx, dy)    // exécution du tracé 
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Don't close, the question's very real, just a little bit too French for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Just give me a minute to start Google Translate here, and....Voila!

Comment: Please use english, StackOverflow is not a multi-language site.

Comment: With all respect: Consider to ask the questions in English to reach a wider audience.

Comment: To the OP, you need to handle `WM_GETDLGCODE` and let Windows know you want to handle dialog keys. Can't give you the answer in French, I can only read French, can't write.

Comment: @Georg Fritzsche: If you consider the tags `c`, `delphi`, `vb`, `pascal`, it seems to be multilingual.

Comment: @phi: Alright, let's talk in C then ;)

Comment: @phimuemue - that's stretching the definition of language. Besides, there's policy about this: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/

Comment: Don't forget to accept (click the "V") if an answer worked for you.

Comment: this worked fine for me. Please accept Cosmin's answer as it is awesome, and really a great answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this to your component's class:

```
procedure HandleDlgCode(var Msg:TMessage); message WM_GETDLGCODE;
```

and then in the implementation section:

```
procedure TComponentClass.HandleDlgCode(var Msg:TMessage);
var
  M: PMsg;
begin
  Msg.Result := DLGC_WANTALLKEYS or DLGC_WANTARROWS or DLGC_WANTCHARS or DLGC_HASSETSEL;
  if Msg.lParam <> 0 then
    begin
      M := PMsg(Msg.lParam);
      case M.message of
        WM_KEYDOWN, WM_KEYUP, WM_CHAR:
        begin
          Perform(M.message, M.wParam, M.lParam);
          Msg.Result := Msg.Result or DLGC_WANTMESSAGE;
        end;
      end;
    end
  else
    Msg.Result := Msg.Result or DLGC_WANTMESSAGE;
end;
```

I've just copy-pasted this code from my own numeric editor, so it works.

Comment: You don't call this method yourself. When the user types anything into your text editor, Windows will first send the WM_GETDLGCODE to your window to see if it wants to handle that. Normally controls don't need to handle arrow keys, tab keys, enter and escape, so Windows can use those for dialog naviagion. For the rare control that do need to process those keys, you need to provide an WM_GETDLGCODE handler to let Windows know you want the keys. The `"message WM_GETDLGCODE;"` tells Delphi this is the handler for WM_GETDLGCODE.

Comment: Add `DLGC_WANTTAB` to the list at the beginning of the procedure.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the way it is done!
This is the way we did things before Delphi, in 1996.
There no need for this complicated Windows stuff.

You are making an editor.
Delphi already has 2 editors build-in.

1. TMemo
2. TRichEdit.

Start with TMemo as your parent, and you have a ready made editor, no need to capture cursor keys.

```
interface

type
  TMyComponent = class(TMemo)   
  //                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^<<- use this as your parent class

protected
    procedure KeyPress(var Key: Char); override 
  ...

 implementation

 procedure TMyComponent.KeyPress(var Key: Char);
 begin
   inherited;
   //it works just like this, TMemo does everything.
 end;
```

In fact you can leave out `KeyPress` and start working on other stuff.

No need to use lowlevel code. You are doing it **too complex**.

Get a book an delphi component design. Even for an older Delphi, not much has changed.
Every hour spend reading a book on this subject will save 20 hours of coding time.

Good luck.

Comment: Johan, but months I work on a component that does not base on TMemo. actually that is a component that makes viewing and editing of web page
tnack yous

Comment: Which component is is based on? Give us the name please.

Comment: GeckoSDK uses OLE, COM and interfaces, very complicated code to mess with. Read Essential COM by David Box ISBN 0-201-63446-5

Comment: Downvoted because this doesn't really help the people who come along and have the same issue with controls and arrow keys, which is really a general problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Procedure Tform1.TraiteMessages(Var msg : TMsg; Var Handled: boolean);
var
  dx, dy : integer;
begin
  dx := 0;
  dy := 0; 
  With msg do
  begin
    IF Message = WM_KEYDOWN then
    begin
      Case  wparam of
        VK_LEFT  : dx := -1;
        VK_RIGHT : dx :=  1;
        VK_UP    : dy := -1;
        VK_DOWN  : dy :=  1;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  Mouvement(dx, dy);
  Handled := ((dy <> 0) or (dx <> 0));
end;
```

That cleans up your method... now, you should place a breakpoint on your IF statement, and another on your Case conditions to determine first and foremost if your message hook is ever being triggered, but also if the message being handled is what you would expect.

Does your component properly catch Key events? Do you have another visual component focused? Have you set your form's "KeyPreview" property to True?

You may also want to try using a TApplicationEvents control to deal with your key message hook (if your component is non-visual).

Take a look at [this unit](http://svn.lakraven.com:81/svn/OpenSource/LakRemotes/Source/OneRemote.pas) on my SVN repository (username and password are both "anon" without quotes) as it demonstrates how to intercept and handle key inputs even on non-visual components.

Hope this helps, and good luck!

Comment: I guess you're supposed to provide your own `Mouvement`; What you're showing is a generic way to handle all 4 direction keys with one single procedure. Declare your own `Mouvement` procedure that takes 2 integer parameters (`procedure Mouvement(const dx, dy:Integer)`)

Comment: A webbrowser does not sound like a non-visual event. Any component based on TWinControl will have all this build-in.